# Generate Software Bill Of Material SBOM for AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I am working with AOSP 9 and 11 to build a android based embedded system.

For several review task I require a list of all software packages, libraries, etc. that are used to build and/or get installed in the final image plus their versions.

Is there a good and reliable way to generate this SBOM for AOSP?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this article: [Create a software bill of materials (SBOM)](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/create-sbom?hl=en) in the AOSP docs.

However, it does not mention the AOSP/Android versions this works with, and does not seem to work for version 11.

Answer (score 0):

They didn't mention in the documentation but seems like that functionality was added in [Android 14](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/android14-release/core/main.mk#2216)

([Android 13](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/android13-release/core/main.mk#2216) doesn't seem to include it)

So far I was just able to get some sbom files (not sure about how accurate they really are though) when using some third party demo services but they are VERY expensive.

I gave a try to https://oss-review-toolkit.org/ort/ but without luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience of generating an SBOM for a custom firmware image, which included first-party C/C++ code, three different filesystems, six kernel, and two Qemu images, I found the process to be quite intensive. Keeping track of all the repositories, source codes, and build scripts required a significant amount of effort.

However, incorporating binary analysis into the process proved to be a pivotal strategy. It significantly streamlined the identification and documentation of all the software components involved. Among the commercial tools available for this purpose, I have had a positive experience with Netrise. Their tool facilitated a more efficient and manageable approach to creating a comprehensive SBOM for such a complex and non-standard project.

I hope this insight proves helpful for your AOSP project, especially considering the complexity and scale of Android-based embedded systems.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No affiliation with any tool. Authentic experience.